# What is the surface area of the plane $x+2y+2z=12$ cutoff by $x=0, y=0$ and $x^2+y^2=16$

Tags: calculus

> What is the surface area of the plane $x+2y+2z=12$ cutoff by $x=0, y=0$ and $x^2+y^2=16\,?$

I am unable to solve this question since it involves $z$ variable too.

Comment: maybe cut off by x>0 and y>0?

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The cylinder

$$x^2+y^2=16$$

cut off an ellipse from the plane $$x+2y+2z=12$$

The projection of the ellipse in the x-y plane is given by the circle:

$$x^2+y^2\leq16$$

with radius $R=4$ and area $A=\pi R^2=16\pi$.

The ratio between the area of the circle and the area of the ellipse is given by the $\cos \alpha$, $\alpha$ being the angle between the normal to the plane and the $z$ axis.

Thus: normal to the plane: $\vec n(1,2,2) \implies \cos \alpha=\frac{2}{3}$.

> The **area of a quarter of ellipse** is thus:
>
> $$S=\frac32 \cdot 4\pi=6\pi$$

Answer (score 2):

First, let me know what do you think about given equations?

here, x+2y+2z=12 is a plane cutting X,Y&Z axes at 12,6,6 respectively.

x=0 is a plane i.e. YZ-plane & y=0 is XZ-plane.

x^2+y^2=16 is a circular cylinder with radius 4 and Z-axis as its axis.

Now trace all these and you will get some part of plane x+2y+2z=12 inside the cylinder b/w axes- planes. This is the portion for which to find the surface area and take projection of this portion on xy-plane , you will get 1/4 of circle of radius 4 with centre at origin.( say this circular region R)

Now, write the equation of plane in form of Monge's equation i. e.  z=6-(x/2)-y
and find it's partial derivatives with respect to x and y both.

formula for surface area is,  S=$\iint \ ds $ over R.

here, dS =$ \sqrt( p^2 + q^2 + 1 )\ dx dy $;where p and q are partial derivatives of the Monge's equation with respect to x&y respectively.

p=-1/2  , q = -1 ; so ds=(3/2) dx dy

Now, S =3/2$\iint \ dx dy $ over R

you can see, S= (3/2)area of 1/4 of circle of radius 4 with centre at origin.

therefore S =(1/4)24$\pi$ = 6$\pi$

Comment: Thanks. I understood it clearly.

Comment: So, do you accept it. Any if you face any problem just let me know