# Finding surface area of plane $x+2y+2z=12$ cut off by planes $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}=16$.

Tags: integration, vectors, surface-integrals

I already saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569045/what-is-the-surface-area-of-the-plane-x2y2z-12-cutoff-by-x-0-y-0-and-x2). But the method discussed there is not familiar to me. Rather, I am used to the formula below for calculating surface integral:

$$\int\int\vec{F}.\vec{n} dS=\int\int\vec{F}.\vec{n}\frac{dxdy}{|\vec{n}.\hat{k}|}$$
$$or, \int\int\phi dS$$

Taking projection in $xy$ plane, I have $z=0$, $\vec{n}=\frac{1}{3}(\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+2\hat{k})$. So, $|\vec{n}.\hat{k}|=\frac{2}{3}$. Now, the surface integral becomes:

$$\frac{3}{2}\int_{x=0}^{4}\int_{y=0}^{\sqrt{16-x^{2}}}(x+2y-2)dydx$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\int_{x=0}^{4}(x\sqrt{16-x^{2}}+16-x^2-12\sqrt{16-x^2})dx$$

But my result does not seem to match with the answer $6\pi$. I don't know if I did wrong somewhere. Any help is appreciated. Thank you...

Comment: The question is already answered.
May refer to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569045/what-is-the-surface-area-of-the-plane-x2y2z-12-cutoff-by-x-0-y-0-and-x2

Comment: Everything is fine but why do you have an integrand? It should simply be $\frac{3}{2} \int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}} \, dy \, dx$

Comment: @MathLover any insight on why not to use any integrand?

Comment: You have already established $\int dS = \frac{3}{2} \int dA$ where $dA$ is the projection of $dS$ in $XY$ plane. $dA = dx \, dy$. If you put an integrand $(x + 2y - 2)$, then you are integrating a scalar field $(x + 2y - 2)$ over the given region and not finding its surface area.